# How can I resolve actionbarSherlock conflict with appcompat?

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I have an old app, builds with actionbarSherlock and appcompact. I have import the project from eclipse to gradle, but when I compile the project the shell shows me a lot of errors that warnsme that there are duplicates. Like this:

```
Error: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: add relevant error log and code for user understanding

Answer (score 1):

You **can't use together** ActionbarSherlock and Appcompat library.

They use the same attributes.

Also Actionbarsherlock **was deprecated** by the author 2 years ago.

I really suggest you switching to appcompat library. In this way you will able to use all the new features and the new support libraries (as the design support library).

Comment: Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299215/actionbarsherlock-conflicts-facebooks-sdk-facebook-android-sdk4-5