# Actionbarsherlock conflicts Facebooks sdk facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, actionbarsherlock

My project is 3 years old which uses  `compile project(':actionbarsherlock')`

Now trying to update facebooks sdk to lates version because **Reminder: Graph API v2.4 will be deprecated on Oct 09, 2017**

After updating to latest `facebook version` I get lots of conflicts error

**gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-with-sources.jar')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

**Error**

[image]

**sherlock.gradle**

[image]

Comment: Please upgrade your all versions

Comment: Any work around without upgrading ?

Comment: `services:4.2.42` too old

Comment: Now using services:9.0.0

Comment: Any one there to help?

Comment: You can't use together ActionbarSherlock and support library.

Comment: I removed it from my .gradle and sherlock .gradle . still same issue